# How to display navigation elements in the same line with toggle button?

Tags: css, html

So, I got a homework from school to create a landing page, of our own design. I thought to have an overlay menu and besides the toggle button, to have three icons within the navbar (2 for social media and one for user account).

I have the below `HTML` and `CSS` code that allows me to use an image as a toggle button for an overlay menu which works fine:

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <ul class="social">
        <li>
            <img src="/images/facebook.svg" alt="">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="logo">MyWebSite</a>
    <img src="/images/menu.svg" alt="" class="menu-btn" id="open-menu">
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    padding: 2em;

    .logo {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 7em;
    }


    .menu-btn {
        float: right;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 35px;
        margin-right: 7em;
    }

    .social {
        display: flex;
        float: right;
        list-style: none;
    }
}
```

Also, I would like to add the icons in front of the toggle menu button. However, what I am getting now using the above code is as you can see in the print screen below which is not the expected results:

[Current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySoUE.png)

What I would to obtain though is as is shown in the below print screen:

[Expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XGH3.png)
Could anyone give me a hint? I'd appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: try using something like an inline-block, check the link below    https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_inline-block_nav     also regarding allignment check navbars https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flexbox` to create desired layout.

**Example**

```css
header {
  background-color: #ee4;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.social-icons-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.social-icons-container i {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
  <h1>Logo</h1>
  <div class="social-icons-container">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
</header>
```